# Get values from .csv closest in time to values in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes I have created using pandas and stored as .csv. Each row of both dataframes has columns with date and times, but the timestamps aren't necessarily same. So, I want to create a combined pandas dataframe such that the 2 are joined on the basis of CLOSEST times.

This is my [first](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xcUCdLIVzuUWE3LTVESU1PVUk/view?usp=sharing) dataframe. This is my [second](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xcUCdLIVzucXB5UmtadUpMWjQ/view?usp=sharing) dataframe. I want to get kp and f107 values for each filename which are closest in date and time to the Avg_time column for each row in the first dataframe. How do I do this?  Is there a merge with method='nearest' type way to do this with pandas?

Comment: Do you give your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge_asof` in Pandas 0.20.2 with a `direction='nearest'`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='file_date'),df2.sort_values(by='AST'), left_on='file_date', right_on='AST', direction='nearest')
```

Output:

```
    Filename  file_date Avg_time                 AST   f107   kp
0  Na1998319 1998-11-16     2:14 1998-11-15 23:00:00  121.8  2.3
1  Na1998320 1998-11-17     2:01 1998-11-16 23:00:00  118.0  2.3
2  Na1998321 1998-11-18     0:38 1998-11-17 23:00:00  112.2  2.3
3  Na1998322 1998-11-18    20:51 1998-11-17 23:00:00  112.2  2.3
4  Na1999020 1999-01-20    22:53 1999-01-19 23:00:00  231.3  0.7
```

Comment: So this isn't working correctly, for the first row, it should join the AST: 1998-11-16 2:00:00 and corresponding f107, kp values: 121.8, 1.7

Comment: Perhaps it is because the Avg_time hasn't been taken into account for file_date, I will merge that with file_date to create a datetime object. Thanks